# Filling Null Value from Last Not Null Value in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 4 columns

```
date   number   Estimate   Client    
----   ------
1      3          10        A 
2      NULL       10        Null
3      5          10        A      
4      NULL       10        Null 
5      NULL       10        Null
6      2          10        A   
.......
```

I need to replace the NULL values with new values takes on the value from the last known value in the previous date in the date column eg: date=2 number = 3, date 4 and 5 number = 5 and 5. The NULL values appear randomly.

This needs to be done in Hive.

Answer (score 8):

This about sliding window;

Here is my table content;

```all
hive> select * from my_table;
OK
1       3       10      A
2       NULL    10      NULL
3       5       10      A
4       NULL    10      NULL
5       NULL    10      NULL
6       2       10      A
Time taken: 0.06 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

All you need to do is to slide over a window between preceedings and current row and find most recent not null value. `LAST_VALUE` windowable function has an argument to ignore null values as boolean. `LAST_VALUE(<field>,<ignore_nulls> as boolean)`;

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(`date`, LAST_VALUE(`date`, TRUE) OVER(ORDER BY `date` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)),
    COALESCE(number, LAST_VALUE(number, TRUE) OVER(ORDER BY `date` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)),
    COALESCE(estimate, LAST_VALUE(estimate, TRUE) OVER(ORDER BY `date` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)),
    COALESCE(client, LAST_VALUE(client, TRUE) OVER(ORDER BY `date` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
FROM my_table;
```

The result will be;

```all
OK
1       3       10      A
2       3       10      A
3       5       10      A
4       5       10      A
5       5       10      A
6       2       10      A
Time taken: 19.177 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using standard hiveql joins.  This should work on all versions of hive.  Table c merges closest date of the client that is not null.  Later table d merges on the number associated with that date.  Using coalesce the appended value is only used when the number is null.

```
select c.date
, coalesce(c.number,d.number) as number
, c.client
, estimate
from
    (select date
     , max(prior_date) as prior_date  -- nearest date not null number
     , value
     , estimate
     , a.client
     from
         (select date
           , value
           , estimate
           , client 
           from table_have
         ) a
        left outer join
        (select date as prior_date -- dates without nulls
          , client 
          from table_have 
          where number is not null
        ) b
        on a.client=b.client
        where date > prior_dates
        group by a.client, date, value
   ) c
 left outer join
  (select date
   , number
   , client
   from table_have
   where number is not null
  ) d
  on c.client = d.client and c.prior_date=d.date
  group by c.date, c.client, estimate
;
```

This query could be optimized more by using common table expressions similarly as used in the alternate solution.  However, this solution does not require N repetitions of lines and should work universally.  The number N required in the other solution may not be static as such this solution may work for the more general case.

Comment: Did the solution i left work for you?  If so could you accept the answer so the community can see that a solution to the question exists.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQL then below query cann help. Else you can use pandas ffill and bfill function .

```
select primary_key_val,country,
COALESCE(country, LAST_VALUE(country, TRUE) OVER(partition by primary_key_val order **by eff_start_dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as upd_country,**
eff_start_dt from dim_acct_keys order by primary_key_val,eff_start_dt
```

Some Data for example:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| primary_key_val  | country  | upd_country  | eff_start_dt  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| act1010          | USA      | USA          | 20190101      |
| act1010          | NULL     | USA          | 20190102      |
| act1010          | NULL     | USA          | 20190103      |
| act1012          | USA      | USA          | 20190101      |
| act1012          | NULL     | USA          | 20190102      |
| act1012          | MEX      | MEX          | 20190103      |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty tricky question, because Hive doesn't support recursive CTEs or correslated subqueries, which would be the usual way to solve this type of problem.

The only pure Hive way I can think of is to do a bunch of self joins. You'll have to do as many as maximum length of consecutive nulls in your data.

```
--add in row numbers
with T as
(select select *, row_number() over (order by date) rn
 from mytable)
--main query
select T.date, 
       case when T.number is not null then T.number
       else when T1.number is not null then T1.number
       else when T2.number is not null then T2.number end as number
       --repeat this N times 
       --where N is the length of the longest sequece of consectutive nulls 

       -- add in your other columns here
from T 
join T T1 on T1.date = t.date - 1
join T T2 on T2.date = t.date - 2
--repeat this N times
```

Comment: We have around 1 million records and you cannot predict how many nulls will be there and hence this is not solution